# insert execution to database

Tags: java, mysql

i want to insert the result of my coding to database, how can i do it?
i have a coding that use java mail to get email, the code run successfully, but then i want to store it (the email) to my database.

this is my code :

```
package ta_aing;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import ta_aing.connection;

public class baca_email {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        connection datMan = new connection();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "email", "password");
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
            Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
            for (Address address : in) {
                System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
            }
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
            System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
            System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
            System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());

            String sql = "insert into email (sender, sent_date, subject, content) values (address.toString, msg.getSentDate,msg.getSubject,bp.getContent)";

            Connection conn;
            conn = datMan.logOn();
            PreparedStatement statement;

        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What the hell has this to do with `php`?

Comment: something wrong with this line `store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "email", "password);` is it typo?

Comment: yeah sorry, just a typo, because i want to remove my email and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i done with it.. thanks for all who trying to helping..

```
package ta_aing;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import ta_aing.connection;
/**
 *
 * @author Yoas
 */
public class cobaaaaa {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        connection datMan = new connection();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "email", "password");
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            System.out.println(inbox.getMessageCount());
            Message [] msg = inbox.getMessages();


            Connection conn;
            conn = datMan.logOn();

            for (int c=0;c<msg.length;c++){
                Address[] in = msg[c].getFrom();

            for (Address address : in) {
                System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
            }
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg[c].getContent();
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
            System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg[c].getSentDate());
            System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg[c].getSubject());
            System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());

            Statement st;

            st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

            for(int i = 0;i<in.length;i++){
                st.executeUpdate("insert into email values(null,'"+in[i].toString()+"','"+msg[c].toString()+"','"+msg[c].getSubject()+"','"+bp.getContent()+"')");
            }

            }

            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DO not set the attributes in query string, use ? instead for prepared statement, JDBC pools the prepared statements and changes the values of ? on the fly to save space. putting it in query defeats the purpose.

```
String sql = "insert into email (sender, sent_date, subject, content) values (" +
        "?, ?,?,?)";

 PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
 statement.setString(1,address.toString());
 statement.setString(2,msg.toString());
 statement.setString(3,msg.getSubject());
 statement.setString(4,bp.getContent());
 statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: it's says "cannot find symbols" what does i need to type in my code before that?

Comment: i already tried to chang address.toString to become in.toString.. but a new error showed. it says java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
s.executeUpdate(sql);
```

the conn is object for the connection with database

Comment: it's says : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'address.toString' in 'field list'.. do i put it wrong or do i need to type something else before that?

Comment: it is for the incorrect sql syntax check your sql query properly